# Validation on selecting text and dropdown. if one is used, both musts be used

Tags: asp.net-mvc

[image]

There is a textbox and a dropdown list box. If textbox is selected then shows a validation for dropdown which means dropdown should also be selected and If dropdown is selected then shows a validation for textbox which means textbox should also be selected If none is selected then do not show any validation.
And I want the condition on Model class in mvc.

```
<table class="simple">
<thead>
      <tr>
          <th  colspan="2">Heading  </th>
      </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr>
        <td>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model.prop2,new 
           {@class = "form- control font-9 p-1" })
       </td>
       <td>                                                     
          @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => 
          m.prop1))                                                                                                
         .DataTextField("Type")                                                                                             
         .DataValueField("Id")                                                                                              
         .OptionLabel(PleaseSelect)                                                                                              
         .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" }))                                                                                                     
  </td>
</tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model.prop4,new 
           {@class = "form- control font-9 p-1" })
       </td>
        <td>                                                     
           @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => 
           m.prop3))                                                                                                
          .DataTextField("Type")                                                                                             
          .DataValueField("Id")                                                                                              
          .OptionLabel(PleaseSelect)                                                                                              
          .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" }))                                                                                                     
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Model Class is -

```
    public class ViewModel
    {
         public int? prop1 { get; set; }

         public decimal? prop2 { get; set; }

         public int? prop3 { get; set; }

         public decimal? prop4 { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class

```
public class Custom : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //Get your model and do magic!
        var model = (yourmodel)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        //Your condtions
        if ((model.prop1== null && model.prop2 == null) || (model.prop1!= null && model.prop2 != null))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult("You must select both of them");
        }

    }
}
```

now add your custom Annotation

```
public class RefractionFinalViewModel
{
     [custom]
     [Display(Name = "Select type")]
     public int? prop1 { get; set; }

     public decimal? prop2 { get; set; }

     public int? prop3 { get; set; }

     public decimal? prop4 { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.prop3 )
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.prop3 , new SelectList(your items, "Id", "type"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.prop3 )
```

Or you can use Foolproof package

```
[RequiredIf("prop2!= null", ErrorMessage = "prop1")]
public int? prop1{ get; set; }
[RequiredIf("prop1> 0", ErrorMessage = "prop2")]
public decimal? prop2{ get; set; }
[RequiredIf("prop4!= null", ErrorMessage = "prop3")]
public int? prop3{ get; set; }
[RequiredIf("prop3> 0", ErrorMessage = "prop4")]
public decimal? prop4{ get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks.But Can you pls Apply the condition on view .. Under the section Thead Or Tbody? And also there is Two TextBoxes and Two DropdownList.

Comment: @RahulSeth whats your dropdown items?

Comment: @RahulSeth I couldn't get what you want exactly. You have the way. Customize ValidationAttribute base on your needs. I add the view to you see how its work

Comment: @RahulSeth My answer completed with the way you find out.

Answer (score 0):

### Simply I applied the validation on Model Class.

```
[RequiredIf("prop2!= null", ErrorMessage = "prop1 required")]
public int? prop1{ get; set; }

[RequiredIf("prop1> 0", ErrorMessage = "prop2 required")]
public decimal? prop2{ get; set; }

[RequiredIf("prop4!= null", ErrorMessage = "prop3 required")]
public int? prop3{ get; set; }

[RequiredIf("prop3> 0", ErrorMessage = "prop4 required")]
public decimal? prop4{ get; set; }
```